# Finding average

Tags: c

i have writen code below for getting numbers i want to enter as input but when i try to get them and find average of them it is not working properly.

```
const int n;
float max,min;
int i,x=0,z=0;
float ave[n];
printf("How many numbers do you want to enter?\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declared your variable length array `ave` at wrong place. Declare it after getting the input `n`. And declare `n` as `int` instead of `const int` (otherwise modifying a `const` qualified type objects invokes **undefined behavior**).

```
int n;
float max,min;
int i,x=0,z=0;
printf("How many numbers do you want to enter?\n");
scanf("%d",&n);  
float ave[n];
```

Comment: @RoyDictus; This feature is introduced first in C99 . It will work. See section **6.7.5.2 Array declarators** of C99 draft.

Answer (score 4):

Change `const int n; to int n;`
`const int n;` should be initialized during definition time. You declared n as const int and you are trying to store data in to that taking from input.

Answer (score 3):

You have two cases of undefined behavior. The first is that you try to modify a constant (`n` is a constant and should not be modified). The second is that when you declare the array you use the uninitialized `n` which will be zero, and therefore create a zero-length array which you then continue to write into.

Comment: There's a third if n is <= 0.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you declare

```
float ave[n]
```

before you give *n* a value. So *n* == 0.

To fix it, give `ave[]` a bigger fixed size OR allocate memory to it after reading *n*.

Comment: So n == undefined, not necessarily 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic array instead for this.here the memory space is created only at the run time. The corresponding code segments are as follows:

```
int* ave;
ave = (int*)malloc(i*sizeof(int)); 
for (j=0;j<n;j++)
  {
     ave[j]=j;                            // the pointer can be used as an array
     printf("%d\n",ave[j]);
  }
```